# DownloadList: Proper Implementation >

Tags: java, android, list, download

I am new to Android development and I am currently trying to create a download app.

I want to add info like in the image in my app but don't know how to create the same

Screenshot

[image]

For example my mainactivity will have diffrent buttons with diffrent links i want them to download and show the info about the current progresss in the DownloadList actity something like in the image.
I'll be using the Fetch2 android libraryfor downloading.

Please help me achieve this.